# How to add CTFrame to UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, core-text, uipageviewcontroller, ibooks, ctframe

The goal is to format and show text as like as iBooks style pages.
For this I take `UIPageViewController`, specify transition for needed animation and generate `UIViewController` collection and etc.
To show text I place `UITextView` into each `UIViewController` of collection.

And to split text for pages automatically I have made my own procedure with:

`[NSString sizeWithFont:...]`.

Thanks for the info from here - [How does the iBooks App format the text on separate pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236177/how-does-the-ibooks-app-format-the-text-on-separate-pages/5236373#5236373)

Everything is working but not so fine as I wish. `NSString` is not very convenient and `UITextView` shows text without good formatting. The splitting is not good enought too =)

Additionally I have tried splitting with `Core Text`.
The approach is showed here - [How to split long NSString into pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812692/how-to-split-long-nsstring-into-pages)

It even works. `Core Text` splits well and it has many other good features. But! I couldn't use the values of splitted by Core Text text with `UITextView`. To show splitted by Core Text pages I must use `Core Text` techniques.

The quesion is: How to create a `CTFrame` and add/draw it for each `UIViewController` of collection for `UIPageController`?

I suspect that it is just impossible. If so, please suggest any idea to realize needed features.

And please excuse me for my question, I am new for iOS programming.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this, but it looks to me like you can get the fitted string range from the CTFrame.

```
CTFrameRef ctFrameRef = // get this from CTFrameSetter
CFRange cfRange = CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange(ctFrameRef);
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(cfRange.location, cfRange.length);
```

Then range can be used to carve up the original string.

Comment: If I understand you right, you suggest to convert resulted CoreText ranges to NSString ranges?

Comment: Yes, then you can examine the end of NSString substringWithRange: to see where the page break is.

Comment: And what to do if it is large? Start to substruct word by word from the end? =) I will try to, at least to compare. Thanks for the idea. But what about adding natural CTFrame to UIViewController? Does anybody know the answer?

Comment: I have tried... CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints provides really uncompatible with UITextView result.